# php - criar ficheiro txt e adicionar todos os registos novos nesse mesmo

Tags: php, txt

Boas,

Estou criando uma function que criará um novo log.txt, se já exitir apenas escreve os novos dados.

Mas está dando erros, visto que estou a testar, e clico REFRESH ao browser ele só fez isto.

```
 ficheiro log.txt \\
 ola
 /n
```

Eu queria corrigir os problemas e adicionar mais segurança nos ficherios

```
$path_log = 'inc/logs/log1.txt'; 
$log_msg = 'ola'. PHP_EOL;
log_editor($path_log, $log_msg);

function log_editor($path_log, $log_msg) {

   $Handle = fopen($path_log, 'wb');

   if (file_exists($path_log)) {    

    fwrite($Handle, $log_msg. '\n');
    //file_put_contents($file, $contents);
    fclose($Handle);        

   } else {

    fwrite($Handle, $log_msg);
    fclose($Handle);         
   }     
}
```

Onde estou errando...?

Comment: Deu certo minha resposta amigo? Era isso mesmo?

Comment: Olá Snoopy12, sei que você não é obrigado a avaliar minha resposta. Mas leve em consideração  que ninguém no SOpt é obrigado a responder perguntas também. E o que nos levam a fazer isso é a recompensa que nos é dado pelos "perguntadores". Se houver algum erro na minha resposta, compartilhe comigo! Mesmo que você não tenha gostado da minha resposta, da minha didática ou do meu "aproach". Qualquer dúvida estou à disposição.

Answer (score 0):

Você está colocando o ponteiro do arquivo sempre no inicio usando o `mode` **`w`**. Desta forma, ele sempre irá escrever em cima do que já foi escrito.

Para escrever no final do arquivo, você precisa usar o **`a`**. Assim:

```
$Handle = fopen($path_log, 'a');
```

Desta forma ele irá começar a escrever no final do arquivo.

Outra coisa, usando o `mode` `a` você não precisa verificar se o arquivo existe. Pois se não existir o próprio comando irá criá-lo. Logo esse pedaço do código não é necessário:

```
if (file_exists($path_log))...
```

Então, eu deixaria o código assim:

```
$path_log = 'inc/logs/log1.txt'; 
$log_msg = 'ola'. PHP_EOL;
log_editor($path_log, $log_msg);

function log_editor($path_log, $log_msg) {

   $Handle = fopen($path_log, 'ab');

   fwrite($Handle, $log_msg);
   fclose($Handle);

}
```

Veja mais na **[documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php)**

Comment: Se a pasta não existir, ele vai criar ?
Na pergunta, criaria todo o diretório?

Comment: @PedroAugusto não... Cria apenas o arquivo. O "ficheiro" que ele diz é arquivo. Provavelmente ele é de portugal. https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/ficheiro/5174/

Comment: Caso ele queira criar as pastas, basta utilizar `mkdir(dirname('inc/logs/log1.txt'), true);`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr isso mesmo.